# Anguarjs Directive at Form Level, accessing all fields and checking for validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In a form (itemSelectionForm), I am rendering multiple tables with ng-repeat. And in each table I have radio buttons which have names appended with index. Now,   I want to write an angular JS directive (selectAtleastOneItemToReturn) that I would put on the form (with select-atleast-one-item) which will do form validation based on children tables radio button. Now, I don't know how I access those children tables radio buttons and their values in that directive so that I can write validation code. And, if radio buttons value changes I want to do validation again and again. And if the form is invalid , the next button would be disabled. The HTML is as below.

```html
<div class="panel-group" data-ng-form="itemSelectionForm" select-atleast-one-item>
  <div class="panel panel-default" data-ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body">       
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="inputRadios{{$index}}" value="option 1"  data-ng-model="item.action" required/>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td>{{item.description}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="inputRadios{{$index}}" value="option 2" data-ng-model="item.action" required/>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">Option 2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="inputRadios{{$index}}" value="option 3" data-ng-model="item.action" required/>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">Option 3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right">    
  <button type="submit" class="btn green-button left space-left" data-ng-disabled="itemSelectionForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="goForward()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is probably to pass down the form object to the directive, and put a `$watch` on the property you need, which would probably be `$error` in your case - although I'm not very clear on what you're trying to achieve actually...

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);  
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $log){
    $scope.items = [
        {
            action: 'fooAction',
            description: 'Foo'
        },
        {
            action: 'barAction',
            description: 'Bar'
        }
    ];
});    
app.directive('selectAtleastOneItem', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            frm: '=selectAtleastOneItem'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch('frm.$error', function(newVal, oldVal){
                console.log(newVal);
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-form="itemSelectionForm" select-atleast-one-item="itemSelectionForm">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item.description}}
                <input type="radio" name="inputRadios{{$index}}" ng-model="item.action" required>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwkmy20j/1/

Hopefully that gets you going a bit.

Comment: Thanks.....but I have items where each item has 3 actions.........user should select one specific action on atleast one item......and I want to put validation on form level using directive.....now in directive I want to access all those dynamically generated radios with dynamic name, and if the conditions meet, the form would be valid otherwise would set the form as invalid........if user changes action on any of the items.....the directive should do the validation again and again.....I do not want to watch form.error